# Overwrite elements in std::shared_ptr to array, what got wrong?

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers

I have following header :

```
#ifndef MY_TEMPLATE_CLASSES_H
#define MY_TEMPLATE_CLASSES_H

#pragma once

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <typename T, size_t N> class Array {
private:
  std::shared_ptr<T[]> ptr;

public:
  explicit Array(const T arr[N]);
  void print();
};

template <typename T, size_t N> Array<T, N>::Array(const T arr[N]) {
  ptr = std::make_shared<T[]>(N);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = arr[i];
  }
}

template <typename T, size_t N> void Array<T, N>::print() {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::cout << &ptr[i] << ":" << ptr[i] << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

#endif // MY_TEMPLATE_CLASSES_H
```

and the main file:

```
#include "my_template_classes.hpp"
#include <variant>

// C++17 at least
#if (__cplusplus < 201703L)
//# error " You should compile with -std=C++17"
#endif

using namespace std;

int main() {
  static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L,
                "This file expects a C++17 compatible compiler.");

  // create template class
  int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Array<int, 5> a(arr);
  a.print();
  return 0;
}
```

the output is: **0x12a9ee0:1 0x12a9ee4:2 0x12a9ee8:3 0x12a9eec:4 0x12a9ef0:842102832**

compiled with *g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-12)*

**Why the last element in address 0x12a9ef0 is not 5?**

Comment: Using `shared_ptr` with arrays was introduced in c++20. I don't think this should even compile... but apparently it does. Godbolt gives a compile time error with newer gcc versions, but works on trunk with `-std=c++20` flag.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/sf6zP668s) is an example with some different compilers.

Comment: In VS2022 with C++20 standard it behaves correctly